# Substitute "Your Name" field for anonymous shown on posted comments

Tags: comments

I am using the 'Corporate Clean' theme.  I have allowed anonymous posting of comments for basic pages. When a person posts, there is a an input field called 'Your Name'.  However when the comment is posted, Anonymous is showed instead.  I would like to know how to substitute the Anonymous for the 'Your Name' field or if not, have the 'Your Name' show in the title line of comment.

thanks in advance.

Update : ok I have loaded a test site with bare minimum modules and tested comments again.  It works this time - no issues.  I can only assume one of the modules I have installed is causing this as I have not edited any files by hand.  What is the best way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Installing the modules one by one would determine the issue, if it's module related, however depending on how many modules that is it may be time consuming.  Also, make sure that the corporate clean theme does not have a template override for comments.  It would be somewhere in sites/all/themes/corporate_clean/templates/X.

Comment: Found the culprit!  Module called 'Comment Goodness' - shows that it has to be patched to correct.  I still need to figure out how to do this in my cpanel environment.  Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 0):

I found it was the [antispam](https://www.drupal.org/project/antispam) module and created a [bug + patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2882913)